# Root Privileges and Risky Commands

Tags: sudo, sudoers

```
user ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/vim /etc/httpd/confs/httpd.conf
user ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/less /etc/httpd/confs/httpd.conf
```

I think if these scripts are written in sudoers, "user" can cause problems on the server because s/he can execute arbitrary commands. Are there any other commands which should not be allowed in sudoers? I would appreciate if you explain the reasons as well.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than allowing vim. Try `sudoedit`.

> user ALL=(ALL) sudoedit /etc/httpd/confs/httpd.conf

Force users to run `cat` instead of `more`

> user ALL=(ALL) cat /etc/httpd/confs/httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to restrict access, It is important to know which programs can be escaped or run other shell commands. This specifically is the reason for `sudoedit` as mentioned above.

eg: If your user is allowed to run `ed` as root, that user is able to run an escaped shell command as root.

I am not willing to go through /bin/ and tell you what programs allow shell escapes, but there are a lot. When you are whitelisting a program (for a reason) check the man page for the words `shell escape`. Maybe there is another option that doesn't allow escapes.

I don't recall specifically, and can't look it up right now, what other vulnerabilities I know to watch out for.